# RxJS run async tasks Array.prototype.map in parallel bulks / queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

Let's say I am having an array of variables, like this: [`Sasha`, `Misha`, `Caitlyn`, `...String`] (`string[]`) and so on. It has a big `.length` about ~10k elements, or so.

And I'd like to run an async parallel task with them, but not with all at once, like `Promise.all`, but in bulks, like this:

```
0 <= return await result
1 <= return await result, then next 2 (or N)
 2
 3
  4
  5
   6
   7
```

Of course, I can do it in various ways, like iterating primitives with `for-loop` and making promises inside, then run them, or use [`p-limit`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-limit) for example, but I heard that `RxJS` with its operators can help me with that.

According to the RxJS [bufferCount](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferCount) is looking just like the thing that I am looking for, but I can't find the necessary example still.

P.S. *If it's possible, I don't like to recreate my array of primitives in another variable and have two various arrays of ~20k primitives and ~20k promises. I prefer to iterate primitives by bulk (N) then form promises, await them to respond, and iterate to the next bulk (N)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how exactly you want to block the async calls.

Assume you have N input values, and you want to process them in groups of size
M.

Do you want to block the processing of the next group until all items in the
current group are done? (This more closely matches your "return await result,
then next N" requirement).

If so, then `bufferCount` is the way.

```js
from(members).pipe(
  bufferCount(N),

  // concatMap completes an async operation for each group in sequence. Nothing
  // happens with the next group until the current group is done.
  concatMap(async (groupOfN) => {
    // process group
  });
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `bufferCount` is an option too, but it seems like it could be achieved much easier with `MergeMap` with using with the second arg.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

async function t(members: string[]) {
  await from(members).pipe(
    // try / catch block is optional
    mergeMap(async obj => { // remember to use `async` for awaiting result
      console.log(obj + '1') // any async action you do, http requests, or DB updates
    }, 2), // where 2 represent parallel
  ).toPromise()
};

t(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']);
```

Comment: The concurrency behavior with `mergeMap` will be different to what you get with `bufferCount`. With concurrency argument N, `mergeMap` will take in new values one at a time until it is processing N values concurrently. When one completes, it takes in another.